# How to write a PostSharp Invoke aspect to simplify cross thread control updates

Tags: c#, winforms, postsharp, multithreading

When I want to update controls across threads this is how I generally end up doing it:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { SomeProcedure(); });
```

The suggested way to do it is actually to call the invoker for the specific control you want to update, but 99% of the time the form (i.e. 'this' in my example) and the control are going to have been created on the same thread so I really like doing this way for simplicity's sake.

I was thinking though that it would be nice if I just had a PostSharp aspect to put on top of SomeProcedure that would wrap it in that mess of a statement for me.

And go... (oh yeah, 100 bonus pts to first usable answer :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand _exactly_ what you want, especially with regards to your second paragraph.  But does PostSharp's example code help at all? http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/multithreading

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't programmed thread access before on WinForms, but I have done it with PostSharp + Silverlight.  So with a bit of googling, I'll give it a shot.  No guarantees that it works though!

```
[Serializable]
public class OnGuiThreadAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    private static Control MainControl;

    //or internal visibility if you prefer
    public static void RegisterMainControl(Control mainControl) 
    {
        MainControl = mainControl;
    }

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (MainControl.InvokeRequired)
            MainControl.BeginInvoke(eventArgs.Proceed);
        else
            eventArgs.Proceed();
    }
}
```

And the idea is at the start of your application, register your main/root control with the attribute.  Then any method you want to ensure runs on the main thread, just decorate with `[OnGuiThread]`.  If it's already on the main thread, it just runs the method.  If it's not, it will promote the method call as a delegate to the main thread asynchronously.

EDIT: I just figured out (it's late) that you're asking to use the specific invoking method for the target control you're using.  Assuming that you decorate *instance* methods on subclasses for your controls:

```
[Serializable]
public class OnGuiThreadAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //you may want to change this line to more gracefully check 
        //if "Instance" is a Control
        Control targetControl = (Control)eventArgs.Instance;

        if (targetControl.InvokeRequired)
            targetControl.BeginInvoke(eventArgs.Proceed);
        else
            eventArgs.Proceed();
    }
}
```